# Net Core MVC - Change Font size

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an MVC Core App with automatic scaffolding.
I am trying to change the font size for my html View.
How would I change font size? in bootstrap.css? and also I see many font sizes, not sure where to look for. I did not find a class  "form-actions" in bootstrap.css

```
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a> </p>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <b>Find by Brand:</b> <input type="text" name="ParamBrand" value="@ViewData["currentBrand"]" />
            <br />
            <b>Find by Color:</b> <input type="text" name="ParamColor" value="@ViewData["currentColor"]" />
            <br />
            <b>Find by Weight:</b> <input type="text" name="ParamWeight" value="@ViewData["currentWeight"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your `_layout.cshtml`. There you will see, which css files are loaded in which order.

You will see something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

That means, that site.css is loaded after bootstrap. You can put any overrides into to site.css and it will override your bootstrap rules:

```
.no-color {
   font-size: 48px;
}
```